# If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , not divisible by 3 show there $\exists t \implies 3^t < n < 3^{t+1}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, contest-math

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , not divisible by 3 show there $\exists t \implies 3^t < n < 3^{t+1}$

By the division algorithm:

$$n = 3a + r \implies 0 < r < 3$$
For some $a$

But I cannot do anything else.

$$3^{t} < n < 3^{t+1} \implies t < \log_{3}(n) < t+1$$

But that still doesn't help.

Does it relate to the floor function?

Comment: Is the number $t$ some real number, $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Try first proving that if $n$ is any number at all, then there is a $t$ such that $t<n<(t+2)$.  Then try proving that if $n$ is odd, then there is a $t$ such that $2t<n<2(t+1)$.  After these warm-up exercises, it should be clear how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ 3^k\,$ is strictly increasing so some $\,3^k > n.\,$ Let $\,3^k\,$ be the least such. Then $\,3^{k-1} \le n,\,$ so $\,3^{k-1}< n\,$ by $\,3\nmid n.\,$ Hence $\, 3^{k-1} < n < 3^k.$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, the proof shows that if $\,n\,$ is not equal to any element of a strictly increasing sequence of naturals (starting at $1$) then it must lie strictly between two elements of the sequence.

Comment: How does it justify:

$$3^{k-1} \le n$$ Though?

Comment: @Amad27 If $\,3^{k-1}\le n\,$ were false, then $\,3^{k−1}>n,\,$ contra our choice of $\,3^k\,$ as the least power of $\,3\,$ that is greater than $\,n.\,$ Above we used [well-ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) (or least number) principle, i.e that a nonempty set of naturals has a least element.